# Press Enter key to continue with conditions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keyboard

i want a javascript function or solution that will be click button when press <kbd>enter</kbd> key. but it have some conditions as shown in this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWUed.png

conditions is when cursor show in "in1" input (or onFocus in "in1" input) and then user press <kbd>enter</kbd> key. "a1" button will be click. and when cursor show in "in2" input and then user press <kbd>enter</kbd> key. "a2" button will be click and so on.

my html code

```
<form action="xxx" method="get">
  <ul class="form-section" id="section_24">
    <li><label>No.1 </label>
        <table border="0">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input id="in1" type="text" name="a1"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button id="a1" type="submit" name="button_action" value="send_a1">send</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </li>

    <li><label>No.2 </label>
        <table border="0">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input id="in2" type="text" name="a2"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button id="a2" type="submit" name="button_action" value="send_a2">send</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </li>

    <li><label>No.3 </label>
        <table border="0">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input id="in3" type="text" name="a3"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button id="a3" type="submit" name="button_action" value="send_a3">send</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

regards.

Comment: You're sure you're not just looking for the Konami code ?

Comment: Where is your Javascript code? What have you done?

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly straight forward. Please have a look at the jQuery documentation as well.
http://api.jquery.com/keypress/
http://api.jquery.com/prop/
http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

**jQuery:**

```
$('input').keypress(ev){
    if(ev.which == 13){
        ev.preventDefault();
        $('#' + $(this).prop('name')).trigger('click');
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FNWs8/)

Comment: dear @Andy ,i try it but it not work for me. when i press Enter, it show button_action=send_a1 in url only. (ex. http://localhost:8080/connectdb/testclick.jsp?a1=001&button_action=send_a1&a2=&a3=# or http://localhost:8080/connectdb/testclick.jsp?a1=&button_action=send_a1&a2=002&a3=#) thanks.